# How to Associate LVM Messaging Service with Existing Campaign

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I have a simple app that sends about 100 SMS messages per day to my company’s employees using the Twilio API. We never send messages to people who haven’t applied to receive them and signed a contract to that effect. I have 1 phone number which I purchased from Twilio.

Every few weeks I get a somewhat threatening email message from Twilio saying

```
You’re receiving this email from Twilio because you’ve sent SMS or MMS messages 
to U.S. numbers from one or more unregistered ten-digit long code (10DLC) phone 
numbers in the past 60 days.
```

Now the emails are saying they are going to block our messages starting Aug 31 and we are starting to panic.

I have no idea how to proceed. I’m begging for advice at this point. Thank you in advance to anyone who can tell me how to deal with this company.

I have spent many hours reading dozens of FAQS that their emails point to and doing everything possible that they suggest and require in an effort to comply.

I have registered an A2P Brand, correctly as far as I can tell. In the console its status says **VERIFIED**.

I have created a Low Volume Mixed use case campaign, and the console status says **VERIFIED**.

I have created, and submitted for vetting, THREE Low Volume Mixed A2P Messaging Service services. The first two were denied, for what, I have no idea, although the application seems to assume that one is sending unsolicited messages, and demands the opt-in and opt-out text of those solicitations – which is so far removed from our use case that my answers to those questions could not possibly satisfy their requirements.

I am very confused about the relationship between a brand, a campaign, and a message service. But I believe that my campaign is associated with one of the 2 denied message services. Both of those services show the status **NO SENDERS IN SERVICE**.

The third message service shows no errors – which I hope to heaven means it actually made it through the vetting process. But when I try to change the campaign to point to it, (AS DIRECTED BY THE THREATENING EMAILS!!), the process throws up an error – **We have temporarily disabled Campaign edits!**. It suggests deleting the campaign and starting over – something I have now done three times in the past several months that I have been trying to resolve this.

I have contacted Twilio support several times. The only response I have ever received is *I am transferring your request to our 10DLC Onboarding team, who will provide further assistance.*